# xslt function to separate a string with delimiter

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have a string. I want an XSLT  function that can separate every two characters of the string with a delimiter '|'. E.g.:

Input `ABADFEREWQ`

Output `AB|AD|FE|RE|WQ.`

Comment: What you have tried post the code  ?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using XSLT 2.0, you can use `replace()`...

**XML Input**

```
<root>
    <string>ABADFEREWQ</string>
</root>
```

**XSLT 2.0** (<kbd>[WORKING EXAMPLE](http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWvjQeQ)</kbd>)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="string">
    <xsl:copy>
      <!--
      Inner replace() adds '|' after every 2 characters.
      Outer replace() strips off the trailing '|'.
      -->
      <xsl:value-of select="replace(
                                replace(
                                    normalize-space(),
                                    '(.{2})',
                                    '$1|'),
                                '\|$',
                                '')"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<root>
   <string>AB|AD|FE|RE|WQ</string>
</root>
```

If you're stuck using XSLT 1.0, here's an example that is very close to Rudramuni TP's, but slightly simpler...

**XSLT 1.0** (<kbd>[WORKING EXAMPLE](http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWvjQeQ/1)</kbd>)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="string">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:call-template name="delimString">
        <xsl:with-param name="string" select="normalize-space()"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="delimString">
    <xsl:param name="string"/>
    <xsl:variable name="remainder" select="substring($string,3)"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring($string,1,2)"/>
    <xsl:if test="$remainder">
      <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
      <xsl:call-template name="delimString">
        <xsl:with-param name="string" select="$remainder"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**XML:**

```
<root>
<string>ABADFEREWQ</string>
</root>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="string">
    <xsl:call-template name="stringPipe">
        <xsl:with-param name="var1" select="."/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="stringPipe">
    <xsl:param name="var1"/>

    <xsl:value-of select="substring($var1, 1,2)"/><!--get first two chars -->
    <xsl:variable name="var2">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring($var1, 3)"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:if test="string-length($var2) > 0"><xsl:value-of select="'|'"/></xsl:if><!--after first two chars, if text still found, then insert '|' symbol -->
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="string-length($var2) > 2"><!--after first two chars, rest of string's length is greater than two, then loop process to insert '|' symbol -->
            <xsl:call-template name="stringPipe">
                <xsl:with-param name="var1" select="$var2"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise><!--after first two chars, rest of string's length is NOT greater than two, then display the text -->
            <xsl:value-of select="$var2"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result:**

```
    AB|AD|FE|RE|WQ
```

Comment: Hi Rudramuni, thanks so much for your help.I am trying to send the output through a field which is defined in another template, while doing so it is throwing error "var2 not defined", can you please tell me if i need to make this variable global

Comment: @Fatima - You should update your question with your XSLT so we can see how you're trying to use this answer.

Comment: @DanielHaley I'm new to this site, i'm trying to send the section of code to you, but not able to find, can you share your email id, i can mail it to you.

Comment: @Fatima - If you look at your original question, you should see "edit" along the bottom. Click edit and add the code to your original question. Don't forget to format the code (http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).